How to Implement Reidemeister Moves for 3D Closed Knots in Python?
I’m working on a project that involves analyzing and manipulating 3D closed knots. Specifically, I want to implement the Reidemeister moves to simplify knot diagrams programmatically. I’m using Python for this task.
Here are the main challenges I’m facing:

Representation:
How should I represent a 3D closed knot in a data structure that allows easy application of Reidemeister moves? I’m considering using a planar graph representation, but I’m unsure how to handle the 3D aspects.

Reidemeister Moves Implementation:
• Type I: Adding or removing a twist in the knot.
• Type II: Moving one strand completely over another.
• Type III: Sliding a strand over a crossing point.
How can I algorithmically detect when these moves are applicable and apply them without breaking the knot’s integrity?

Maintaining Knot Integrity:
After performing moves, how can I ensure that the resulting knot is still valid and represents the same topological structure?

Visualization:
I’m using Matplotlib for 3D visualization, but I’m struggling to visualize the changes after each Reidemeister move. Any suggestions on integrating the moves with a visualization library would be appreciated.


I have only tried visualizing and representing the knot in different ways but I have not figured out how to actually perform the reidemeister moves like how explained in knot theory

Interesting question, but it's off topic here, since it's not a specific programming problem; try math.stackexchange.com or cs.stackexchange.com. To get some ideas about representations, etc., maybe search for existing open source projects about knot theory and see how they handle it.
